# Location of 'locate' documentation

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

The 'locate' command is used in several ipython notebooks (example below), however, I am unable to locate documentation for the command. I would appreciate help finding the appropriate documentation.

```
profile_dir = ! ipython locate
profile_dir = profile_dir[0]
profile_dir
```

Many thanks
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with IPython, but it looks as if the `locate` command is used to find the [IPYTHONDIR](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html#envvar-IPYTHONDIR) or a specific [profile](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/config/overview.html#profiles).

According to the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/config/overview.html#locating-these-files) on IPython's homepage:

> From the command-line, you can quickly locate the IPYTHONDIR or a
>   specific profile with:
>
> `$ ipython locate`
>   `/home/you/.ipython`
>
> `$ ipython locate profile foo`
>   `/home/you/.ipython/profile_foo`
>
> These map to the utility functions:
>   [`IPython.utils.path.get_ipython_dir()`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/api/generated/IPython.utils.path.html#IPython.utils.path.get_ipython_dir) and
>   [`IPython.utils.path.locate_profile()`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/api/generated/IPython.utils.path.html#IPython.utils.path.locate_profile) respectively.

Comment: I'm red-faced. I'll bet I looked at that page 10 times and read right over it. Many thanks.

Comment: The code I presented is actually from an ipython notebook. Interestingly enough the '!ipython locate' line functions properly leading me to believe that 'locate' is part of the python/ipython environment.

Comment: Looking at the ipython gallery notebook:    http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Part 01 Running Code.ipynb"                           Any command line program can be run using ! with string interpolation from Python variables:"

Comment: @Ron - Well, that is interesting.  I'll remove the last part of my post then.  As I said, I'm not very familiar with IPython. ;)